# Create a .csv file with one column of header information above multiple columns below in MATLab

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to update database files. The file structure has 1 column of values for the first ~40 rows (which I treat as a string) and then 3-4 columns of data beneath it. I am able to import the data into MATLab and do the operations that I need to, but I do not know how to export the data, removing the commas from the first 40 rows and writing the header information at the top.

Eventually I would like to iterate this to do a substitution of all negative numbers to -999 for all files in a folder.

```
Example data of desired format:
/secchi_depth=3.2
/cloud_percent=NA
/wind_speed=24
/wave_height=0.3
!
! COMMENTS
!
!
!
!
!
/missing=-999
/delimiter=comma
/fields=wavelength,ag,ap,ad
/units=nm,1/m,1/m,1/m
/end_header
400,1.276121,0.335431,0.135773
402,1.231213,0.337944,0.133908
404,1.187686,0.340812,0.131316
```

The code I have written so far:

```
filename = uigetfile;


%IMPORTFILE(FILETOREAD1)
%  Imports data from the specified file
%  FILETOREAD1:  file to read

%  Auto-generated by MATLAB on 10-May-2016 17:16:37

% Import the file
newData1 = importdata(filename);

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));

end

[r,~] = size(textdata)
[~,c] = size(data)

data(data<0) = -999


csvwrite('Test.csv',data,r,0)
```

Comment: You can **not treat** the output as `.csv` but as a text file with `.csv` suffix. You can use http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

Comment: So this means I need to add the commas in myself? Is there an easy way to do this? I am a noob at exporting beyond using xlsread and xlswrite. I have been wrestling with how to use fprintf for this application all morning,

Comment: Second option is to append two csv files using matlab or system shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier than it looks. Use [dlmwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)...

Suppose we have `Header` in `cell` array with dimension of Hx1 and `Data` in numeric array with dimension MxN.

```
%% Write Header
dlmwrite('Test.csv',Header{1},'');           %% Write first row with no delimiter
for line={Header{2:end}}'                    %% Assign rest of the Header to line and loop over its elements
  dlmwrite('Test.csv',line,'','-append');    %% Append every line with no delimiter
end

%% Write the Data
dlmwrite('Test.csv',Data,'-append')          %% Append Data with default delimiter - comma
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually got it to work by using fprintf for the headers then csvwrite to append the rows of data after the fact.